# Trying to make school report in latex for first time. Can't get equations to work

Tags: equations

```
\begin{equation}
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], then new_list = [(2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5), (1\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5), (1\cdot2\cdot4\cdot5), (1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot5), (1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4)] = [120, 60, 40, 30, 24]
\end{eqution}

If \(my_list = [25,5,4,15,3], then new_list = [(5*4*15*3), (25*4*15*3),(25*5*15*3), (25*5*4*3), (25*5*4*15)] = [900, 4500, 5625, 1500, 7500]\)
```

I am trying to make a school report in Latex for the first time, and I'm finding myself on using more time on the latex programming than the Python and R code in the assignment. I have tried using both \begin and \end equation and ( and ) without success. I also tried to write it as normal text, but then i got some error due to the *.

Would appreciate any tips, would really like to get good in latex, but I won't have time for that before the due date of this report, so I am strongly considering to just use word.

EDIT: Tried to fix the spelling error, but now I get a error concerning the subsection under the equation.

```
 \section*{Problem 1.1}
    \lstinputlisting{problem_1.1.py}

    \subsection*{Explanation}
   blablalblalbalblalbalblalbal a list my\_list, produce a \_list where all the integers, new\list[i], are the product of all the integers in my\_list, except my\_list[i]. Let’s try two examples to illustrate the problem. 
    \begin{equation}
    my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], then new_list = [(2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5), (1\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5), (1\cdot2\cdot4\cdot5), (1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot5), (1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4)] = [120, 60, 40, 30, 24]
    \end{equation}


    %If \{my_list = [25,5,4,15,3], then new_list = [(5*4*15*3), (25*4*15*3),(25*5*15*3), (25*5*4*3), (25*5*4*15)] = [900, 4500, 5625, 1500, 7500]\)


    \subsection*{Result}
    \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering 
            \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{out1.png} 
            \caption{Output of PyCharm console.}
            %Label gjør det enkelt å referere til ulike bilder.

    \end{figure}

    \section*{Problem 1.2}

    \lstinputlisting[language=R]{assig1R.r}

    \subsection*{Explanation}
    "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"

    \subsection*{Result}

    \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering 
            %Scale angir størrelsen på bildet. Bildefilen må ligge i samme mappe som tex-filen. 
            \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{out2.png} 
            \caption{Output of R consolel.}
            %Label gjør det enkelt å referere til ulike bilder.
            \label{fig:test}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEX S.E.! There is a typo. Type `\end{equation}`

Comment: Welcome! I really think you need to at least skim over some introductory material... If you don't have the time to do it, it's not a good idea to switch to LaTeX now. It's like learning a new programming language; you need time to understand the basic philosophy and then build over it. Your code is really *far* away to what an equation in LaTeX should be...

Comment: Also you should use `align`. \begin{align} ... \end{align}

Comment: Thanks sztruks! Take a look at my edited question.

Comment: Hi Rmano, I fully agree with you, but this is the only problem I have. Everything else works well.

Comment: Note it is easier for us to help you if you provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE).
This mean a code we can directly compile to see what is the problem. Without information about the kind of error you have, it is harder for us to address your request.

Comment: So, do you want `\text{my\_list}` or `\text{my}_\text{list}`?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but please do yourself a favour and don't use `[H]` as floating specifier of your figures. This is basically a guarantee for bad placement. Better use something like `[htbp]` and let latex do what it can do best and find the best possible location for the figure.

Comment: Due to the lack of time I decided to try something called Lyx. Very easy and looks great. Will try to learn Latex at a later time. Thanks for all the inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\texttt{my\_list} & = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] , \text{ then}\\
 \texttt{new\_list}& = [(2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5), (1\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5), (1\cdot2\cdot4\cdot5), (1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot5), (1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4)\mathrlap{]} \\[0.5ex]
 & = [120, 60, 40, 30, 24]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

If $\texttt{my\_list} = [25,5,4,15,3]$, then $\texttt{new\_list} = [(5*4*15*3), (25*4*15*3),(25*5*15*3), (25*5*4*3), (25*5*4*15)] = [900, 4500, 5625, 1500, 7500]\)

\end{document}
```

[image]